# Can external users benefit from our Organization Assets Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, external-users

I created a document library to be used as organization assets library for our organization as mentioned in this link @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library .. and i granted "Everyone except external" read access to the library so they can use the templates when they created word & power point files..

but my question is; if external user can also benefit from the organization asset library? for example let say i granted an external user read access on the organization assets library >> then can this external user use the templates inside the library when creating new word and power points files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give an **external user Read permission** to access the **Organization Asset library** , then the external user can use the assets inside the **Organization Asset library**.

---

```
#Create an organization assets library
Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryUrl <URL> [-ThumbnailUrl <URL>] [-OrgAssetType <ImageDocumentLibrary or OfficeTemplateLibrary>] [-CdnType <Public or Private>]
```

- When **Public CDN** is used for asset library, all content in the
  library is **anonymously available for anyone** having the URL.
  Public CDN should be used for non-sensitive assets, like images,
  JavaScripts and css-files. Private CDN respects SharePoint library
  permissions. So if user doesn’t have access to original library,
  content is not displayed. **This also considers external users**.
- If you are planning to use only **Private CDN** configured asset
  libraries, you need to make sure that users consuming the assets have
  access to original libraries. **The simplest option is grant everyone
  a read permission to site hosting asset libraries**.

---

More information, please refer to [this article](https://mattipaukkonen.com/2019/09/26/sharepoint-organization-asset-libraries-explained/).

======================== **Updated Answer** ======================

If you choose to use **Public CDN**, then **all content in the library is anonymously available for anyone having the URL**. Public CDN should be used for non-sensitive assets, like images, JavaScripts and css-files.

**Private CDN respects SharePoint library permissions**, so it can only be accessed by users with permissions to the original document library or storage location. **So if user doesn’t have access to original library, content is not displayed. This also considers external users.**

Comment: ok, now when i run this command `Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryUrl <URL> [-ThumbnailUrl <URL>] [-OrgAssetType <ImageDocumentLibrary or OfficeTemplateLibrary>] [-CdnType <Public or Private>]` i were asked that this operation will allow CDN ,, and i confirm this operation.. so does this mean that the content of this library will be available to anyone how have the URL (even external users or anonymous users?).. now in my case i want to create Org Asset Library to save some templates to be used when creating word and powerpoint files..

Comment: Hi, John John. Thanks for your reply. I have updated my answer. If an Answer is helpful, please mark and upvote it.